# Computers unable to connect to internet on router with working connection

Tags: networking, router, internet, connection

Suddenly, computers (I've tried multiple) that were previsouly able to connect to the network cannot connect both wired and wireless. They connect to the router fine, but are unable to obtain internet access.

The router is working and new computers/phones are able to connect.

I've tried:

- Restarting all devices (routers, computers)
- 'Forgetting' the network
- Deleting network profiles from registry
- Connecting the computers both wired & wirelessly
- Verifying drivers are up-to-date
- Running: netsh int ip reset reset.log & netsh winsock reset catalog

What could be going on? How might I resolve this?

ipconfig returns:

```
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd3e:561f:1697:0:8022:b6ec:2516:9820
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd3e:561f:1697:0:70af:c825:e20c:8520
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8022:b6ec:2516:9820%7
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.203
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the clients - Sounds like the router needs resetting and re configuring. What router?

Comment: Its a zyXEL router. Unsure of model number.

Answer (score 0):

The devices can ping the router, which should have the internal address of 192.168.43.1 If this is correct and the router indeed connects to the internet through its WAN link, based on you saying new devices connect fine. Than look into the router's admin web page to see if you have any filters set against these devices.